# Mat-table [dataSource] with async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material, observable

Just spent a few hours trying to figure out why `<table mat-table [dataSource]="data|async">`... wasn't updating when new values were emitted for `data`....

Comment: This could probably be turned into a useful question, if only there were an actual question :)

Comment: I just wanted to add my experience to the site in case someone had the same problem.

Comment: I can not see any questions. Also the best answer do not answer how to use dataSource with async pipe.

Comment: @guerric, you and me both. My guess is that it either is (a) because it isn't question/ answer format or (b) maybe I was doing it wrong and my conclusions aren't valid. Either way, it looks like it has helped some people so I left it up.

Comment: I agree that it would be better as a full question and a full answer, but it's still helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

... It turns out the `async` pipe not only isn't needed, but it breaks change detection somehow. So the correct way to use an observable with `dataSource` is to just give it the data with no pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Your data property wasn't an observable. That's why it didn't work.